# Global variable does not work

Tags: c++, mfc, imagemagick

I'd like to use a global variable(fileposition) in C++ as following.

the fileposition is get from OnDropFile().

When I got a fileposition as following, the fileposition value are changed after display as well.

I don't know the reason.

```
char * fileposition;

...



::OnDropFile()

{

...
MAX_PATH = 260;

char szPathName[MAX_PATH];

::DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0, szPathName, MAX_PATH);

fileposition = szPathName; // 

global_TestView->DoDisplayImage();

...

}
```

TESTVIEW.cpp

```
void CTestview::DoDisplayImage(void)
{
...

m_Image.read(fileposition);
...
}
```

## update

I don't know someone told me this question is duplicated. but I don;t know what should I do for solving this.
Would you please help me ?

Comment: `char szPathName[MAX_PATH];` goes out of scope as soon your function returns. One solution would be making it `static`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Is "char szPathName[MAX_PATH];" sure?  because I use global variable which is" fileposition" If you don't mind Would you please let me know how to use static?

Comment: I have solved. Thanks